# mysql not working with xampp

Tags: mysql, xampp, lampp

Although I've reinstalled the xampp server, mysql cannot start.

Trying to fetch the status, I get :

```
[sk001:/opt/lampp] 18s $ sudo ./xampp status
Version: XAMPP for Linux 5.6.20-0
Apache is running.
MySQL is running.
ProFTPD is running.
```

Xampp manager looks like this :
[image]

And it's impossible to start from the manager.
What's going wrong ? How to fix it ?

**Edit**
The output of `lsof -i :3306` is :

```
[sk001:/opt/lampp] $ lsof -i :3306
[sk001:/opt/lampp] 1 $
```

Comment: Can you add the output of following command: "lsof -i :3306"? Maybe there is another program running on that port. If not, it would be helpful to see some log files.

Comment: @MrPixelDream, look at my update.

Comment: That output does not show any cause of your problem, so I would recommend adding the log files of the MySQL Server which should be located under `/opt/lampp/logs` or something like this.

Comment: Just have `error_log`, `php_error_log` and `access_log` in `/opt/lampp/logs/` directory. Nothing related to mysql

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue too, i solved it by:

1. sudo service apache2 stop
2. cd /opt/lampp
3. ./manager-linux-x64.run (start xampp manager, yours could be x32 or anything)
4. Click 'Start All' button

It should now work properly.

Comment: Only `Apache Web Server` started successfully. `MySQL Database` and `ProFTPD` failed (displayed stop after starting).